# Linear programming explanation in Algorithms by Sanjoy Dasgupta

Tags: linear-programming, algorithms

I am reading about simplex algorithms in a textbook titled *Algorithms* by Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vairani.

> On each iteration, simplex has two tasks:
>
> 1. Check whether the current vertex is optimal (and if so, halt).
> 2. Determine where to move next.
>
> As we will see, both tasks are easy if the vertex happens to be at the
> origin. And if the vertex is elsewhere, we will transform the
> coordinate system to move it to the origin!
>
> First let's see why the origin is so convenient. Suppose we have some
> generic LP \begin{align}\max&\quad c^\top x\\\text{s.t.}&\quad Ax\le b\\&\quad x\ge0\end{align} where $x$ is the vector of variables, $x = \begin{pmatrix}x_1&\cdots&x_n\end{pmatrix}$. Suppose the origin is feasible. Then it is certainly a vertex, since it is the unique point at which the $n$ inequalities $\{x_1\ge0,\cdots,x_n\ge0\}$ are tight.
>
> Now let's solve our two tasks. For task 1, the origin is optimal if and only if all $c_i\le0$. If all $c_i\le0$, then considering the constraints $x\ge0$, we can't hope for a better objective value. Conversely, if some $c_i > 0$, then the origin is not optimal, since we can increase the objective function by raising $x_i$.
>
> Thus, for task 2, we can move by increasing some $x_i$ for which $c_i > 0$. How much can we increase it? Until we hit some other constraint. That is, we release the tight constraint $x_i\ge0$ and increase $x_i$ until some other inequality, previously loose, now becomes tight.
>
> At that point, we again have exactly $n$ tight inequalities, so we are at a new vertex.
>
> For instance, suppose we're dealing with the following linear program. \begin{alignat}2\max&\quad2x_1+5x_2\\\text{s.t.}&\quad2x_1-x_2\le4\tag1\\&\quad x_1+2x_2\le9\tag2\\&\quad-x_1+x_2\le3\tag3\\&\quad x_1\ge0\tag4\\&\quad x_2\ge0\tag5.\end{alignat} The simplex can be started at the origin, which is specified by constraints $4$ and $5$ . To move, we release the tight constraint $x_2\ge0$. As $x_2$ is gradually increased, the first constraint it runs into is $-x_1 + x_2\le3$, and thus it has to stop at $x_2 = 3$, at which point this new inequality is tight. The new vertex is thus given by $(3)$ and $(4)$.
>
> So we know what to do if we are at the origin. But what if our current vertex $u$ is elsewhere? The trick is to transform $u$ into the origin, by shifting the coordinate system from the usual $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ to the local view from $u$. These local coordinates consist of (appropriately scaled) distances $y_1,\cdots,y_n$ to the $n$ hyperplanes (inequalities) that define and enclose $u$:

[image]

> Specifically, if one of these enclosing inequalities is $a_i\cdot x\le b_i$, then the distance from a point $x$ to that particular "wall" is $y_i = b_i - a_i \cdot x$. The $n$ equations of this type, one per wall, define the $y_i$'s as linear functions of the $x_i$'s, and this relationship can be inverted to express the $x_i$'s as a linear function of the $y_i$'s. Thus we can rewrite the entire LP in terms of the $y$'s. This doesn't fundamentally change it (for instance, the optimal value stays the same), but expresses it in a different coordinate frame. The revised local LP has the following three properties:
>
> 1. It includes the inequalities $y\ge0$, which are simply the transformed versions of the inequalities defining $u$.
> 2. $u$ itself is the origin in the $y$-space.
> 3. The cost function becomes $\max c_u + c'^\top\cdot y$, where $c_u$ is the value of the objective function at $u$ and $c'$ is a transformed cost vector.

I am having difficulty in understanding trick in above statement mentioned below:

> The trick is to transform $u$ into the origin, by shifting the coordinate system from the usual $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ to the local view from $u$. These local coordinates consist of (appropriately scaled) distances $y_1,\cdots,y_n$ to the $n$ hyperplanes (inequalities) that define and enclose $u$.

What does the author mean by shifting the coordinate system to the local view from $u$ in the above statement?

What does "local coordinates consist of distances to the $n$ hyperplanes" mean?

Answer (score 2):

For the original problem, we examine the origin, if it is optimal, we halt. Suppose not, from the origin, we know what to do.

Now, suppose we are at vertex $u$, the passage discuss a procedure to make $u$ to be the origin of the new coordinate system, we denote it using $y$ rather than $x$.

The trick is look at those active constraints at $u$, we can use them to define an affine transformation of the coordinate system to a new coordinate system by defining $y_j = b_j-a_j^\top x$. Since the constraints are active at $u$, $b_j-a_j^\top u=0$ in the new coordinate system, the new coordinate at location $u$ corresponds to the new origin since $y_j=b_j-a_j^\top u=0$.

Also, previously, all the feasible points would satisfies $b_j-a_j^\top x \ge 0$, hence in the new coordinate system, $y_j=b_j-a_j^\top x \ge 0$.

As an example, consider the example that you provided:

\begin{alignat}2\max&\quad2x_1+5x_2\\\text{s.t.}&\quad2x_1-x_2\le4\tag1\\&\quad x_1+2x_2\le9\tag2\\&\quad-x_1+x_2\le3\tag3\\&\quad x_1\ge0\tag4\\&\quad x_2\ge0\tag5.\end{alignat}

Now in the first move, we have reached $(0,3)$, we want to convert this vertex to the origin of the new coordinate system.  Constraint $(4)$ [Define $y_1=x_1$] are active. Constraint $(3)$ is active too [Define $y_2=3+x_1-x_2$].

We can express $x$ in terms of $y$: $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=3+y_1-y_2$.

Let's compute the new objective function:

\begin{alignat}2\max&\quad2x_1+5x_2=2y_1+5(3+y_1-y_2)=15+7y_1-5y_2\\\text{s.t.}&\quad2y_1-(3+y_1-y_2) \le 4\tag{6}\\&\quad y_1+2(3+y_1-y_2) \le 9 \tag{7}\\&\quad-y_1+(3+y_1-y_2) \le 3 \tag{8}\\&\quad y_1 \ge 0 \tag{9}\\&\quad 3+y_1-y_2 \ge 0 \tag{10}.\end{alignat}

Now, using the new coordinate system, we are at the origin of the new system in the format that you are familiar with and the procedure can be repeated.

Remark:

- Usually, simplex algorithm is implemented using a tableau.
- Rather than distance, I prefer calling it slack as in slack variable. Strictly speaking $2x\le 6$ and $x\le 3$ are both equivalence inequalities $6-2x$ and $3-x$ gives different values though. When the slack is $0$, the constraint is active, when the slack is negative, the constraint is violated.